# Best practice for config variables in Python

Tags: python

So recently my programs have become more complex, and are starting to require more configuration. I've been doing the following, however it feels wrong...

```
class config:
    delay = 1.3
    files = "path/to/stuff"
    name = "test"

dostuff(config.name) #etc...
```

I've never been a fan of the ALL_CAPS_VARIABLE method, and was wondering if there is an "official" way to do this, and if there is anything wrong with my current method.

Comment: What kind of configuration are you doing with this?  This does have a bit of a smell to it, considering it's not much of anything that the actual program seems to be interfacing with.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your method. Different projects use different conventions. E.g., Django uses `settings.SOME_CONSTANT` (where `settings` is actually a module), others use a `dict` instead of a class, and so on. I might use a dict or class named in all caps, but not the attributes or keys, so you'd get something like `CONFIG.name`.

Comment: Addendum to the Django example: consider creating a `config` module instead of a class that lives in your project (package). That generally allows more freedom.

Comment: @Makoto Most of my programs are games in PyGame, and need things like the screen size, and screen refresh rate etc. I don't want to have to change everything if I want to make the screen bigger, so I use a constant. I guess "configuration" is a bit misleading.

Comment: @Evert I like that idea actually... makes things more organized.

Comment: Looks like someone's gone on a downvote spree on the answers here: there's actually a *deleted* answer with essentially that same (moduel-style config) suggestion (I presume it's deleted because it was downvoted).

Comment: Why not use the `ConfigParser` module of de standard library: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html

Comment: ALL_CAPS is a style, not a "method". It doesn't affect code execution; the main point is to communicate that the variable is not supposed to change. See PEP 8 for styles: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend use of [python-decouple](https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple). This library allow separate code from configurations(data).

UPDATE:

#### Brief explanation of usage of this library:

Simply create a **.env** text file on your repository's root directory in the form:

```
DEBUG=True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True
EMAIL_PORT=405
SECRET_KEY=ARANDOMSECRETKEY
DATABASE_URL=mysql://myuser:mypassword@myhost/mydatabase
PERCENTILE=90%
#COMMENTED=42
```

**OBS:** put `*.env` in your `.gitignore`

On your python code, can be used in this way:

```
from decouple import config

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)
EMAIL_HOST = config('EMAIL_HOST', default='localhost')
EMAIL_PORT = config('EMAIL_PORT', default=25, cast=int)
```

Comment: Curious how this compares to reading from a yaml file?

Comment: Or using [os.environ](https://www.doppler.com/blog/environment-variables-in-python)?

Comment: The advantage over os.environ is that you turn a string into others types such bool, list, int,... with less overhead and without code duplication.